# Why static_assert calls in unused template methods in LLVM

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, llvm

I have next structure of project like this:

> Utils.h

```
template<typename T>
T test() {
  static_assert(false, "Test calls");
}
...
```

> Handle.h

```
#include "Utils.h" // but not call test()
... // something code
```

> Main.cpp

```
#include "Utils.h" // but not call test()
int main { ... // something code
```

But when I compile it, I get static_assert. Why? Because it should not be compiled

I use Xcode 6.3.2

Comment: The templated function is still *parsed*, no code may be generated but the compiler still reads and processes it, including the `static_assert`.

Comment: but why I got static_assert then? In any official documents it is possible to see?